# php call user func, для переменных

Tags: php

Есть простой класс:

```
class Test {

public $var = '123';

function func() {
//как можно вызвать $this->var, при помощи конвертации строки в код? То есть примерно так:
$v = 'var';
echo "$this->"."$v";
//И чтобы получилось echo $this->var
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `echo $this->$v;`

Comment: `echo $this->var`

или если вы не знаете какое имя переменной будет во время выполнения скрипта:

`$name = 'var';  // берем название откуда-то
echo $this->{$name};`

Answer (score 0):

> *как можно вызвать $this->var, при помощи конвертации строки в код?*

Передавайте строку с названием свойства класса **var** вторым параметром в *[call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php)*, а в теле callback-функции ссылайтесь на значение этого свойства через псевдопеременную **$this** и переменную **$v**:

```
class Test
{
    private $var = '123';

    public function func()
    {
        return call_user_func(function($v){
            return $this->$v;
        }, 'var');
    }
}

echo (new Test)->func(); // 123
```